# Remove quotes from string built from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have user controller input like so (the length and # of items may change):

`str = "['honda', 'toyota', 'lexus']"`

I would like to convert this into an array, but I'm struggling to find the best way to do so. `eval()` does exactly what I need, but it is not very elegant and is dangerous in this case, since it's user controller input.

Another way is:

```
str[1..-2].split(',').collect { |car| car.strip.tr("'", '') }

=> ["honda", "toyota", "lexus"]
```

But this is also not very elegant. Any suggestions that are more 'Rubyish'?

Comment: Could you provide some more context about why you're working with a string in this way? The cleanest solution to your problem is likely to change the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
# match (in a non-greedy way) characters up to a comma or `]`
# capture each word as a group, and don't capture `,` or `]`
str.scan(/'(.+?)'(?:,|\])/).flatten
```

Or `JSON.parse` (but accounting for the fact that single quotes are in fact technically not allowed in JSON):

```
JSON.parse( str.tr("'", '"') )
```

---

`JSON.parse` probably has a small edge over the regexp in terms of performance, but if you're expecting your users to do single quote escaping, then that `tr` is going to mess things up. In this case, I'd stick with the regexp.

Comment: I'd strongly advocate the `JSON.parse` approach and steer away from that gnarly regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.parse looks more correct, but here is another alternative:

```
str.split(/[[:punct:] ]+/).drop(1)
```